# Stuck on using dpylr's mutate/summarise to map colors to variable levels

Tags: r, dplyr

I've never been able to figure out a good way to do this.  I'm trying to create a user-function for mapping RColorBrewer colors to variable levels in a data_frame. I'm plotting node colors in igraph and it requires a color vector.  I've made it this far, before getting an error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

 my_data <- data_frame(
    x = sample(c('red','white','foo'),25,T)
 ) 

my_data %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(Blues = brewer.pal(n_distinct(x),'Spectral'))  ## this doesn't work
```

I'd like a working function. Something like the following:

```
function(df,vary){
    df %>%
       group_by(vary) %>%
       mutate(Blues = brewer.pal(n_distinct(vary),'Spectral')) %>%
       select(Blues)
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How many colors do you expect from the result? Three colors of length 25?

Comment: @Psidom, I'd like one column that has three colors. One that matches/corresponds with each level in x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `group_by`, just use `mutate` and generate the colors you need with `brewer.pal(n_distinct(x), 'Spectral')`, and then map the colors to the variables using `match`:

<sub>Notice: I've used the `tidyeval` syntax to capture the variable in NSE style, since we are using a function with `dplyr`. But you can choose to program otherwise if you prefer.</sub>

```
var_to_color <- function(df, var) {
    var <- enquo(var)
    df %>% 
        mutate(Colors = brewer.pal(n_distinct(!!var), 'Spectral')[match(!!var, unique(!!var))]) %>%
        pull(Colors)
}

var_to_color(my_data, x)
# [1] "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FFFFBF" "#FFFFBF" "#99D594" "#FFFFBF" "#99D594"
# [8] "#99D594" "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FFFFBF" "#99D594"
#[15] "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59" "#99D594" "#FFFFBF" "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59"
#[22] "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59"

my_data$x
# [1] "white" "red"   "red"   "red"   "foo"   "red"   "foo"   "foo"   "white"
#[10] "red"   "white" "red"   "red"   "foo"   "white" "white" "foo"   "red"  
#[19] "white" "white" "white" "white" "red"   "white" "white"
```

---

Without using `dplyr`, a function that takes one vector and then maps it to colors probably make more sense:

```
var_to_color <- function(var) brewer.pal(n_distinct(var), 'Spectral')[match(var, unique(var))]

var_to_color(my_data$x)
# [1] "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FFFFBF" "#FFFFBF" "#99D594" "#FFFFBF" "#99D594"
# [8] "#99D594" "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FFFFBF" "#99D594"
#[15] "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59" "#99D594" "#FFFFBF" "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59"
#[22] "#FC8D59" "#FFFFBF" "#FC8D59" "#FC8D59"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works pretty perfectly. Can you tell me why you added the '!!' does?

Comment: It's part of the syntax for `tidyeval` you can read more about it [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). Basically it evaluates a symbol in `dplyr` verbs such as `mutate` and `summarize` as a column.